# How to implement IEnumerable in my specific case?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable

My question has been asked before, but I can't figure it out even with all the previous posts. Clearly I don't understand it correctly.

I had Visual Studio generate a ADO NET Entity Framework Model, Code first from database. In the database I have a table called Finishes (to hold every possible ending to a game, just to clarify). This all works fine. Now I need to implement IEnumerable in order to be able to iterate through it. This far I understand everything. I just can't seem to be able to do it somehow. Maybe someone can shine their light over it so I will understand for once and for all.

Visual Studio has generated two classes;

Checkoutlist.cs:

```
namespace Bull.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;

public partial class CheckoutList : DbContext, IEnumerable
{
    public CheckoutList()
        : base("name=DatastoreConnection")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Finish> Finishes { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Finish>()
            .Property(e => e.First)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Finish>()
            .Property(e => e.Second)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Finish>()
            .Property(e => e.Third)
            .IsFixedLength();
    }
}
}
```

And Finish.cs:

```
namespace Bull.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public partial class Finish
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Total { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string First { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Second { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Third { get; set; }
}
}
```

So the question is; how do I implement IEnumerable in my case? Your help (and possibly explanation) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Code first from database" Code first is approach that generate database from Code but not Code from database

Comment: I don't understand, `Finishes` already implements `IEnumerable<Finish>`. Your `CheckoutList` is the `DbContext` which should not implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks MegaTron. So what you're saying is I'm using the wrong method to begin with and this is my problem?

Comment: why do you need to implement IEnumerable on the classes themselves? couldnt you just take them into simple List<>s?

Comment: Well @bresleveloper, I ran into this problem while trying to 'foreach' through it in another class. Then it told me that I couldn't do it because 'Checkouts' doesn't implement 'IEnumerable'. So I figured I had to implement this in my Checkouts class. Found some examples but I can't get it to work in my case. But like I said, I probably just don't understand it well enough.

Comment: You haven't shown your `Checkouts`-class. Your `CheckoutList` is the `DbContext`, so it is your database instance which you can't enumerate, if you want to enumerate all `Finish` you have to use the `Finishes` property: `using(var db = new CheckoutList()) foreach(Finish f in db.Finishes)Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}",f.First,f.Second,f.Third);`

Comment: @TimSchmelter My Finish class is what you mean with Checkouts class I think. I chose different names in an attempt to make it more understandable for myself. I have no Checkouts class.

Comment: @ReneGijzemijter: you have used these names, i don't know what you've meant with it

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have a class Checkouts, which is a collection of Finish. Checkouts used to be FinishES which was a collection of Finish. But the names started to confuse me so I deliberately changed the latter. I'm sorry if my explanation is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this method:

```
public IEnumerable<Finish> Get()
{
     var query = base.Set<Finish>();
     return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MegaTron this was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to have been of help